# How do I see the original markdown of a post while an edit is in the approval process (and there is no edit history)?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review, revisions-list

I'm trying to see if a suggested edit should be approved ([which inserts line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382806/r-hypergeometric-test-phyper)).

In this case it is important that I manually check the *markdown* for the original post rather than the visual output.

If I click `Improve`, I get a post-edit version of the markdown, not pre-edit.

Is there a way to view the original markdown, pre-edit, when there is no existing edit history?

*Edit*: Since I was typing this up, that post has been edited.  The first revision was what I was reviewing, and the initial post was what I was trying to view.

Comment: This might make sense to mark as dupe of some feature-request for a change to how suggested-edits work.  I didn't look through all of them, but I know some exist.  Do what you must :)

Comment: The second icon down shows the markdown diffs - does this do what you want?

Comment: @ChrisF: Yep!  Missed that.  Post as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second icon down shows the markdown differences.

[image: Markdown differences]

This should show what you want as it shows exactly what each user typed, including the markdown syntax, rather than the rendered output.